# Maximum partition size in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Should we consider any partition limitation like what is recommended for Cassandra (around 100MB) in YugabyteDB too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limit doesn't apply to YugabyteDB. A single partition is still limited to a single tablet which will reside in 1 server, thus it's recommended to not have tablets & partitions larger than ~50GB to make data and workload rebalancing smoother.